# Even Splitters.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

Return an array of characters on which we can split an input string to produce substrings of the same length.

Don't count empty strings after the split.

Here's an example for "banana":

```
"banana".split("a") # => ["b", "n", "n"] (all elements same length)
"banana".split("b") # => ["", anana"] 
(all elements same length - there's only
one element "anana" because the empty string doesn't count)
"banana".split("n") # => ["ba", "a", "a"] (all elements NOT same length)

result: ["b", "a"]
```

Here is my code:

```
def even_splitters(str)
  count = Hash.new(0)
  new_arr = []
  str.chars.map do |e| 
    arr = str.split(e)
    if arr == [] || arr.length == 1
      new_arr << e
    else
      arr.each {|x| count[x] = x.length }
      if count.values.uniq.length == 1
        new_arr << e
      end
    end
  end
  p new_arr
end

puts "-----Even Splitters----"
puts even_splitters("") == []
puts even_splitters("t") == ["t"]
puts even_splitters("jk") == ["j", "k"]
puts even_splitters("xoxo") == ["x", "o"]
puts even_splitters("banana") == ["b","a"]
puts even_splitters("mishmash") == ["m","h"]
```

Comment: hi, please describe how your code is failing and the question will be easier to approach.

Comment: hi, the way I thought didn't realize count will be 0 if it's a empty string.

Comment: yeah, i see how that was surprising. if your question is solved, you can post your own answer or close the question. I'm not sure this question is general enough to be helpful to others.

Comment: No I won't follow your order.

Answer (score 2):

here's couple of suggestions as to where you're going wrong...

```
def even_splitters(str)
  new_arr = []
  # use #uniq here... you don't need to test every 'a' in 'banana'
  str.chars.uniq.each do |e|
    # initialize the hash **inside** the loop, otherwise count is just accumulating as each letter is tested
    count = Hash.new(0)
    # exclude empty strings
    arr = str.split(e).reject(&:empty?)
    arr.each {|x| count[x] = x.length }
      # handle single character strings like "t"which have no values by saving if count.values.empty?
      if count.values.uniq.length <= 1  
        new_arr << e
      end
  end
  p new_arr
end

puts even_splitters("") == []
puts even_splitters("t") == ["t"]
puts even_splitters("jk") == ["j", "k"]
puts even_splitters("xoxo") == ["x", "o"]
puts even_splitters("banana") == ["b","a"]
puts even_splitters("mishmash") == ["m","h"]
```

Here's a more compact solution...

```
def even_splitters(str)
  str.chars.uniq.map do |e|
    str.split(e).reject(&:empty?).map(&:length).uniq.count <= 1 ? e : nil
  end.compact
end
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your solution which fill in my language hole to realize the code, however,  do you mind share more thought or resource about making hash between in loop and outside the loop? # initialize the hash **inside** the loop, otherwise count is just accumulating as each letter is tested

Comment: And in your compact solution, why do you use #compact since you have used #uniq in your loop?

Comment: Oh I see, when you loop "n", it returns "nil". So you need to do that.

Comment: A small problem, Steve. If `str #=> "t"` and `e #=> "t"` then `str.split(e) #=> []`, so `str.split(e).reject(&:empty?).map(&:length).uniq.count #=> 0`, resulting in `e` being (incorrectly) mapped to itself. I believe you can fix that by changing `count <= 1` to `count == 1`.

Comment: It occurred to me that whether `"t"` splits the string `"t"` into equal-size substrings ( `"t".split( "t") #=> []`) depends on how the OP wishes to treat that case. Han, please clarify.

Comment: hi @CarySwoveland I was being guided by one of Han's test cases.... `puts even_splitters("t") == ["t"]` ... to make that print `true` I changed to `<= 1`

Comment: @HanJiang you initialized count right at the beginning, and only once.  So when you're doing "b" you're accumulating the length counts for the "b" test.  When you're later doing "a" you're accumulating the length counts for the "a" test but the "b" results are still in the hash.  By initializing the `count` hash inside the array, you are ensuring you have an empty hash every time you start testing a letter.

Comment: In the compact solution it processes the array ['b', 'a', 'n'] and the result `... <= 1 ? e : nil` means you get returned either the letter... the `e` variable... if the test passes, or `nil` if the test fails, so you end up with `['b', 'a', nil]` then compact gets rid of the `nil` entries so you're left with the final solution `['b','a']`

Comment: Hi @CarySwoveland, can you explain what's "OP wishes to treat that case"? I do not understand.

Comment: Hi @SteveTurczyn, I think I get it why I need to initialize `count = Hash.new(0)` in the loop now. Thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland's question relates to how do you want single-letter input strings to be handled.  i.e. should `even_splitters("t")` return `["t"]` or `[]` ?

Comment: It needs to return `["t"]`, that's what I have given. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: after making a few changes to my code I see it is now very close to @Steve's "compact solution".  I'll leave my answer for its "Explanation" section.

@SteveTurczyn has answered your question and also suggested an alternative method. Here is another.

**Code**

```
def even_splitters(str)
  str.chars.
      uniq.
      select do |c| (str.split(c)-[""]).
                    map(&:size). 
                    uniq.
                    size == 1
      end
end
```

**Examples**

Using Steve's examples,

```
even_splitters("")
  #=> []
even_splitters("t")
  #=> []
even_splitters("jk")
  #=> ["j", "k"]
even_splitters("xoxo")
  #=> ["x", "o"]
even_splitters("banana")
  #=> ["b","a"]
even_splitters("mishmash")
  #== ["m","h"]
```

**Explanation**

Suppose

```
str = "xoxo"
```

The steps are as follows:

```
a = str.chars
  #=> ["x", "o", "x", "o"] 
b = a.uniq
  #=> ["x", "o"] 
b.select do |c| (str.split(c)-[""]).
                map(&:size). 
                uniq.
                size == 1
end
  #=> ["x", "o"]
```

Let's look more closely at `b.select`. The first element of `b` is passed to the block and assigned to the block variable:

```
c = "x"
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
d = str.split(c)
  #=> str.split("x")
  #=> ["", "o", "o"] 
e = d - [""]
  #=> ["o", "o"] 
f = e.map(&:size) 
  #=> [1, 1] 
g = f.uniq
  #=> [1] 
g.size == 1
  #=> true
```

Since `g.size==1 #=> true`, `"x"` is selected.

Next, the second and last element of `b` is passed to the block and the calculations are performed:

```
c = "o"
d = str.split(c)
  #=> str.split("o")
  #=> ["x", "x"] 
e = d - [""]
  #=> ["x", "x"] 
f = e.map(&:size) 
  #=> [1, 1] 
g = f.uniq
  #=> [1] 
g.size == 1
  #=> true
```

so `"o"` is included as well.

Comment: Thank you, Cary. I like how you use #minmax_by to narrow the target and also use #select instead of 'if' statement. It's very clean and elegant.

Comment: Yes, `select` was a good move!